# Accessing uploaded file's content in Activiti user task

Tags: activiti

I have uploaded a file using a user task in activiti (version 6, community edition). How can I access the content of this file and pass it on to the script task?

Comment: Need some more detail as attachments changed significantly between version 5 and 6.
What version are you using?

Comment: version 6 community edition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attachments are associated with tasks.

You can use the TaskService to retrieve the attachment ID's for a given task.
Once you have the ID, you can then use the TaskService to retrieve the attachment details or the Attachment content. 
Hope this helps..